# Nginx server doesnt serve css and js files of my express app

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy

Im trying to create a webrtc app with socket.io and express. On 7000 port of my server. Page is loading but js and css files are not serving from nginx. I tried some configurations from net but i couldnt fix it. If i try to use the location as "/" there is no problem. But i want it to use on mysite.com/rtc location. I hope some one can help me. Thank you. (Btw i have one more app at 8000 port)

My index.ejs ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>WebTutsPlus WebCon</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Tamma+2:wght@400;500;600&family=Josefin+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" /> -->

</head>

<body class="h-100">
  <div class="h-100" id="video_display">

    <div id ="video_container" class="align-items-center" style="margin-top: 10%;">
      <div class="local_div" id="div1" style="">
                <video id="localVideo" class="" autoplay muted playsinline></video>
            </div>
            <div class="remote_div" id="div2">
                <video id="remoteVideo" class="" autoplay playsinline></video>
            </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  

  

  <!-- Import SocketIO for signalling -->
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  <!-- Import WebRTC adapter for compatibility with all the browsers  -->
  <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Import TURN config -->
  <script src="js\config.js"></script>

  <!-- Import script containing WebRTC related functions -->
  <script src="js\main.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

My nginx configuration ;

```
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log; server {
        listen 80;
        server_name website-name;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
 listen 443 ssl;
server_name website-name;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.site/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.site/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        client_max_body_size 128M;
        location ~ \.php$ {
        root /home/ubuntu;
        #  proxy_pass http://ip:8000;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        # With php-fpm (or other unixsockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets): fastcgi_pass127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
  location /rtc {
       root /home/ubuntu/aura-videochat;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_X_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://ip:7000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
   # Increase http2 max sizes
   http2_max_field_size 64k;
   http2_max_header_size 64k;
}
```

My index.js (main app only beginning);

```
'use strict';

//Loading dependencies & initializing express
var os = require('os');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
//For signalling in WebRTC
var socketIO = require('socket.io');


app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get("/rtc", function(req, res){
    res.render("index.ejs");
});

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 7000);

var io = socketIO(server);
```

Comment: Where did you put the static files?  If you go to `https://localhost/rtc", that will redirect to your app on port 7000, but your CSS has an absolute reference to "https://localhost/css/styles.css", which will not proxy to your app.

Comment: My files under public/css/.. and public/js/.. my index.ejs is under public/views/index.ejs. Btw if i try to go myip:7000/rtc im not having css or js errors.

Comment: That config file has the default for https to be /home/ubuntu.  There's no "public" there.

Comment: Because my app files are in /home/ubuntu/aura-videochat

Comment: OK, but that means `https://localhost/css/styles.css` has to come from `/home/ubuntu/css/styles.css`.

Comment: I got you. Im asking `"How can i change it to https://localhost/rtc/css... ?"`

Comment: One way is to change the links in your HTML to read, for example, `href="'/rtc/css/styles.css"`.

Comment: Thanks for help but unfortunately its not working.

Comment: Is your app able to handle static requests for `/css` and `/socket.io` files?  Your app will now have to handle all static requests.

Comment: I added my index.js to main post

Comment: So, are your files now in `/home/ubuntu/public/css` etc?

Comment: My files are in `/home/ubuntu/aura-videochat/public/css/...`